# Error 13 when passing undefined Excel.Workbook variable to subroutine

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have code that passes a declared, but undefined Excel.Workbook variable to a subroutine within an Access database that has always worked well.  The staff using the database are on O365, and it appears to me that those whose version of office has been upgraded can no longer run this code without encountering the Error 13 - type mismatch, while those with older versions (not yet updated) can still run it without issue.

```
Dim wbkADJUST As Excel.Workbook

'irrelevent code omitted, but wkbADJUST is not set

Excel_Reporting 1, strBILLPATH & "Billing\" & "BillExportB.xlsx", _
    "qryFRONTREPORTADJUST", "Adjustments", False, "", "", _
    False, objEXCEL, wbkADJUST

'Which calls to the following sub

Public Sub Excel_Reporting(lngFREEZE As Long, strREPORT As String, _
    strQUERY As String, strSHEET As String, booEVALSHEET As Boolean, _
    strFUNCTION As String, strPRIORFUNCTION As String, booSAVEDB As Boolean, _
    objXL As Excel.Application, wbkOP As Excel.Workbook)

'The subroutine goes on to set the wbkOP Workbook variable
```

I expect the code to take the undefined wbkADJUST variable and set it in the subroutine without issue, which it has always done.  However, in the last week, some, but not all of my client's users have reported the 'Run-time error '13': Type mismatch' error.

This has always worked in the past, what can I do to stop this error?

Comment: Please show the line of code which causes the error with `wbkOP`. Additionally: The parameter `wbkOP` is declared as `ByRef` implicitely. Maybe declaring it `ByVal` explicitely helps out?

Comment: You may have a [references](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/missingreferences.aspx) problem when users have different versions of Office. Which version do you develop in? How do you distribute your database (accdb or accde)? Switching to **late binding** may help, but could be a major task.

Comment: The point at which the error occurs is the call to Excel_Reporting.  I develop in O365, and distribute a full accdb.  However, in my experience, minor updates are rolled out all the time, and not uniformly to all employees at the same time.  The reference point is interesting, it isn't because it expects Excel 14 object library, for example, but if the reference was broken in some way...